# Fit a word into an alphabet grid

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, alphabet

Inspired by a [meme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLbE3.jpg) I saw earlier today.

## Challenge description

Consider an infinite alphabet grid:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
...
```

Take a word (`CODEGOLF` in this example) and make it a subsequence of the grid, replacing unused letters by a space and removing letters at the end of the infinite grid altogether:

```
  C           O           
   DE G       O           
           L              
     F
```

## Examples

`STACKEXCHANGE`

```
                  ST      
A C       K               
    E                  X  
  C    H                  
A            N            
      G                   
    E
```

`ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA`

```
                         Z
                        Y 
                       X  
                      W   
                     V    
                    U     
                   T      
                  S       
                 R        
                Q         
               P          
              O           
             N            
            M             
           L              
          K               
         J                
        I                 
       H                  
      G                   
     F                    
    E                     
   D                      
  C                       
 B                        
A
```

`F`

```
     F
```

`ANTIDISESTABLISHMENTARIANISM`

```
A            N     T      
        I                 
   D    I         S       
    E             ST      
AB         L              
        I         S       
       H    M             
    E        N     T      
A                R        
        I                 
A            N            
        I         S       
            M
```

## Notes

- Trailing whitespaces are allowed.
- You don't need to pad <strike>the last</strike> any line with spaces. For example, if the input is `ABC`, you may output just `ABC` without 23 trailing spaces.
- You may assume input will match `[A-Z]+` regex.
- Alternatively, you may use lower-case alphabet, in which case output will match `[a-z]+`.
- You must use a newline (`\n`, `\r\n` or equivalent) to separate lines, that is a list of strings is not a proper output format.
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so make your code as short as possible!

Comment: Are leading newlines allowed?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Sure, as long as it doesn't mess up grid structure.

Comment: Would it be okay if a non-fatal error stops the program?

Comment: @Zacharý Although I can see how that could save some bytes, I think it's ugly and produces undesired, superfluous output. So no. EDIT: Unless you can make your program non-fatally exit through an exit code or something that wouldn't print exception stack trace or something similar to stderr.

Comment: Okay, my answer doesn't error.

Comment: `list of strings is not a proper output format` Do you mean the list containing each line, or any type of list of strings?  [This meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2216/60043) states that a list of characters (i.e. each element is a single character) is a valid string, mainly because some languages lack such distinction.

Comment: @JungHwanMin Yeah, I realize that.By "list of lines" i mean specifically output like `["AB(...)", "(...)XYZ", "(...)"]`

Comment: Suggested test case: `BALLOON` (two adjacent characters that are the same).

Comment: Go the answer in PHP
https://gist.github.com/elminson/37d3caa43033f901dd100386f7ae7bde

Answer (score 11):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 15 bytes

```
TṪS`?' €…"AZ"ġ>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P@ThzlXBCfbqCo@a1jxqWKbkGKV0ZKHd////Hf1CPF08g12DQxydfDyDPXxd/UIcgzwd/TyDfQE)

### Explanation

```
TṪS`?' €…"AZ"ġ>  Implicit input, e.g. "HELLO"
             ġ>  Split into strictly increasing substrings: x = ["H","EL","LO"]
        …"AZ"    The uppercase alphabet (technically, the string "AZ" rangified).
 Ṫ               Outer product of the alphabet and x
  S`?' €         using this function:
                   Arguments: character, say c = 'L', and string, say s = "EL".
       €           1-based index of c in s, or 0 if not found: 2
  S`?'             If this is truthy, then c, else a space: 'L'
                 This gives, for each letter c of the alphabet,
                 a string of the same length as x,
                 containing c for those substrings that contain c,
                 and a space for others.
T                Transpose, implicitly print separated by newlines.
```

Answer (score 7):

## Java 10, <s>161</s> <s>159</s> 152 bytes

```java
s->{var x="";int p=0;for(var c:s)x+=p<(p=c)?c:";"+c;for(var y:x.split(";"))System.out.println("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".replaceAll("[^"+y+"]"," "));}
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@Nevay*.
-7 byte printing directly instead of returning a String, and converting to Java 10.

**Explanation:**"

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##rZBdb4IwGIXv9yve9KqESXYtY0sFRBSKCn7HJV3VDYdAAI3E@NtZ/ciu3B1Ne/Geps85p1t2YI3t6qfiEctzcFkYn54AwrhYZxvG10AvI8AhCVfAMf9m2WIJuaQK9SyO2HnBipADhRg0qPLG2@nAMjhqCKkCA6n2om6SDF9E3sylo6ylrzjVuPTOm0hFMv@7LptHJU@jsMBClyS/zIv1Tkn2hZJmAhXFGJGWbphtq2N3e45Lvf5g6Aej8WQ6myMlW6eRiEyiCKPFB5JLGS3RMwKBUs@Vekub7j8jkfYe@lprJ0pjvxAWX6Ibk26NY4VjpHuGaXlOGylFoovuJMtYiaVrfYBHARv/LXR/dOX6AdF75lTvEGqZdcPns@lkPAr84aDvUdfpde2O1TYNvUXqdgrqBhIa2Ibtm@J/Wo7td1yTBmRoE2r7bt1eLeI4nkcfYc9P5@oX)

```java
s->{                      // Method with String parameter and no return-type
  var x="";               //  Temp-String
  int p=0;                //  Previous character (as integer), starting at 0
  for(var c:s)            //  Loop (1) over the characters of the input
    x+=p<(p=c)?           //   If the current character is later in the alphabet
                          //   (replace previous `p` with current `c` afterwards)
        c                 //    Append the current character to Temp-String `x`
       :                  //   Else:
        ";"+c;            //    Append a delimiter ";" + this character to Temp-String `x`
  for(var y:x.split(";")) //  Loop (2) over the String-parts
    System.out.println(   //   Print, with trailing new-line:
     "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                          //    Take the alphabet,
        .replaceAll("[^"+y+"]"," "));}
                          //    and replace all letters not in the String-part with a space
```

The first part of the method splits the input-word into parts with a delimiter.
For example: `CODEGOLF` → `CO;DEGO;L;F` or `BALLOON` → `B;AL;LO;O;N`.

The second part loops over these parts, and uses the regex `[^...]` to replace everything that isn't matched with a space.
For example `.replaceAll("[^CO]"," ")` leaves the `C`, and `O`, and replaces everything else with a space.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `B;AL;LO;O;N`?

Comment: -2 bytes: `for(char c:s)x+=p<(p=c)?c:";"+c;`.

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 69 bytes

```c
i;f(char*s){for(i=64;*s;putchar(*s^i?32:*s++))i+=i^90?1:puts("")-26;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5Ba8IwAEbv/orQU9IScG4IM0hJ29hmtqmaurkhgnTrlsOiJNWL@Nu7yO72@r734Kvxd113nSINrH/2xrfo0hwMVNPxE/EtOZ7aG4a@3anwcTTxbRAgpIKp2j0Pw4eJ2y30PIRHY3LtlG7B715peD6oTwQuAwAa6MVlwtIyn3mIOHA0znJ0qzHGW32D/5qsaDxnmzijImU97sf75u11XcnVclGKIp@/8CydsSSOaE/Yd4KKiidcMncmyrnMCiYquuJUcFncS81XezIaDMng2v0B)

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
''jt8+t1)wdh26X\Ys(26e!
```

Uses lowercase letters.

Try it at [MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=%27%27jt8%2Bt1%29wdh26X%5CYs%2826e%21&inputs=stackexchange&version=20.4.1)

#### Explanation

```
''     % Push empty string
jt     % Push input string. Duplicate
8+     % Add 8 to each char (ASCII code). This transforms 'a' 105,
       % 'b' into 106, which modulo 26 correspond to 1, 2 etc
t1)    % Duplicate. Get first entry
wd     % Swap. COnsecutive differences.
h      % Concatenate horizontally
26X\   % 1-based modulo 26. This gives a result from 1 to 26
Ys     % Cumulative sum
(      % Write values (converted into chars) at specified positions
       % of the initially empty string
26e    % Reshape into a 26-row char matrix, padding with char 0
!      % Transpose. Implicitly display. Char 0 is shown as space
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 44 bytes

**40 bytes code + 4 for `-lF`.**

```perl
print map/$F[0]/?shift@F:$",A..Z while@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRCE3sUBfxS3aIFbfvjgjM63Ewc1KRUnHUU8vSqE8IzMn1cHt/39nfxdXd38ft3/5BSWZ@XnF/3Vz3AA)

Comment: The link you've posted is for 46 bytes version.

Comment: @ThePirateBay Thanks!! I knew I hadn't updated something!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 92 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,y=65:x and(y<=ord(x[0])and" "*(ord(x[0])-y)+x[0]+f(x[1:],-~ord(x[0]))or"\n"+f(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRoUKn0tbM1KpCITEvRaPSxja/KEWjItogVhPIV1JQ0tKAC@hWamqDGNppQL6hVayObh1cTjO/SCkmTwkkpan5v6AoM69EI01DydnfxdXd38dNSVOTCyzIBZdy9AvxdPEMdg0OcXTy8Qz28HX1C3EM8nT08wz2BSr/DwA)

Comment: [90 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRoUKn0tbMxKpCITEvRaPSJr8oRaMi2iBWE8hVUlDS0oALaNdVamqDWNppQAFDq1gduJRmfpFSTJ4SSEJT839BUWZeiUaahpKzv4uru7@Pm5KmJhdYkAsu5egX4uniGewaHOLo5OMZ7OHr6hfiGOTp6OcZ7AtU/h8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @Shaggy*

```
;ò¨ £B®kX ?S:Z
·
```

Uppercase input only.

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O/KoIKNCrmtYID9TOloKtw==&input=IkFOVElESVNFU1RBQkxJU0hNRU5UQVJJQU5JU00i)

### Explanation

```
;
```

Switch to alternate variables, where `B` is the uppercase alphabet.

```
ò¨
```

Split the input string between characters where the first is greater than or equal to (`¨`) the second.

```
£
```

Map each partition by the function, where `X` is the current partition.

```
B®
```

Map each character in the uppercase alphabet to the following, with `Z` being the current letter.

```
kX
```

Remove all letters in the current partition from the current letter. If the current letter is contained in the current partition, this results in an empty string.

```
?S:Z
```

If that is truthy (not an empty string), return a space (`S`), otherwise return the current letter.

```
·
```

Join the result of the previous line with newlines and print the result.

Comment: 10 bytes for `r"[^{Z}]"S` seems a bit ridiculous, but I can't find any better way either...

Comment: [17 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O/KoIKNCy1tTRF1nWPhECrc=&input=IkFOVElESVNFU1RBQkxJU0hNRU5UQVJJQU5JU00i)

Comment: [16 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O/KoIKNCrmtYID9TOloKtw==&input=IkFOVElESVNFU1RBQkxJU0hNRU5UQVJJQU5JU00i)

Comment: @Shaggy Good thinking with `kX`!

Comment: Actually I think you can change `kX ?S:Z` to `oX ªS` to save two bytes

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 79

*Edit* As a leading newline is accepted, I can save 2 bytes

```
s=>eval("for(o='',v=i=0;c=s.charCodeAt(i);v%=27)o+=v++?c-63-v?' ':s[i++]:`\n`")
```

For 1 byte more, I can accept lowercase or uppercase input:

```
s=>eval("for(o='',v=i=0;c=s[i];v%=27)o+=v++?parseInt(c,36)-8-v?' ':s[i++]:`\n`")
```

*Less golfed*

```
s=>{
  var i,o,c,v
  for(o = '', v = 1, i = 0; c = s.charCodeAt(i); v %= 27)
    o += v++ ? c-63-v ? ' ' : s[i++] : '\n'
  return o
}
```

**Test**

```js
f=s=>eval("for(o='',v=i=0;c=s.charCodeAt(i);v%=27)o+=v++?c-63-v?' ':s[i++]:`\n`")

function update() {
  var i=I.value
  i=i.replace(/[^A-Z]/gi,'').toUpperCase()
  O.textContent=f(i)
}

update()
```

```html
<input id=I value='BALLOON' oninput='update()' >
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: You can replace the `\n` with a literal newline inside backticks for -1 byte.

Comment: @JustinMariner no I can't, not inside the double quote in eval

Comment: Oh right, that's a shame. My bad.

Answer (score 4):

## C (gcc), <s>91</s> 63 bytes

-28 thanks to ASCII-only

```
_;f(char*s){for(_=64;*s;)putchar(++_>90?_=64,10:*s^_?32:*s++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/eOk0jOSOxSKtYszotv0gj3tbMxFqr2FqzoLQEJK6hrR1vZ2lgDxLXMTSw0iqOi7c3NgLS2tqa1rX/cxMz8zSAWjWUgkMcnb1dI5w9HP3cXZVAcgA)

---

Previous:

```
i,j;f(char*s){while(s[i]){for(j=65;j<91;j++)s[i]==j?putchar(s[i++]):printf(" ");puts("");}}
```

Yes, there's a shorter solution, but I noticed after I wrote this one... [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9TJ8s6TSM5I7FIq1izujwjMydVozg6M1azOi2/SCPL1szUOsvG0tA6S1tbEyRua5tlX1BaAtIAUqetHatpVVCUmVeSpqGkoKRpDZQr1lACMmpr/@cmZuZpAA3SUIqKjAgPCw0JDgoM8Pfz9fH28vRwd3N1cXZyBKn8DwA)

Comment: [82 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/eOk0jOSOxSKtYs7o8IzMnVQPESssv0oi3NTOx1taOt7E0tNbUKra1jbcvKC0BqQUq0dbWtCooyswrSdNQUlDStAbKFGsoARm1tf9zEzPzNIBmaCgFhzg6e7tGOHs4@rm7giT/AwA), [80](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/eOk0jOSOxSKtYs7o8IzMnVaOgtKRYQ0lJUwcolJZfpBFva2Zira0db2NpaK2pVWxrG28PVALSo6FVrK2taVVQlJlXkqahpKCkaV37PzcxM09DsxrIDw5xdPZ2jXD2cPRzdwXLAQA) if leading newline is allowed

Comment: [73](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/eOk0jOSOxSKtYs7o8IzMnVQPESssv0oi3NTOx1taOt7E0tNYsKC0BqQJK2trG22sVa2tbGRtpWgOFizWUlDSta2v/5yZm5mkAtWooBYc4Onu7Rjh7OPq5u4Ik/wMA)

Comment: [63](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/eOk0jOSOxSKtYszotv0gj3tbMxFqr2FqzoLQEJK6hrR1vZ2lgDxLXMTSw0iqOi7c3NgLS2tqa1rX/cxMz8zSAWjWUgkMcnb1dI5w9HP3cXZVAcgA)

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 18 bytes

```
#pbVGp?JqhzNNd=>zJ
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%23pbVGp%3FJqhzNNd%3D%3EzJ&input=antidisestablishmentarianism&debug=0)

Leading newline in output, lowercase alphabet.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
<2\¬0;œṗfȯ⁶$¥€@€ØAY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/GKObQGgPro5Mf7pyedmL9o8ZtKoeWPmpa4wDEh2c4Rv7//9/RL8TTxTPYNTjE0cnHM9jD19UvxDHI09HPM9gXAA)

Comment: `OI<1®;` -> `>2\0;` to save  one byte (I actually did `>2\0;œṗµØAf€ȯ€⁶µ€Y` for 18 too, which I personally find easier to parse)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I think that would fail for `BALLOON` or something.

Comment: You are correct, yes - so it would required another byte with something like `<2\1;¬`; oh well.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Anyways, I'll implement your idea in my answer...done.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
ćIgµ¶?AvDyÊið?ë¼?ć
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/8wNWFiMWX//8SHSWfCtcK2P0F2RHnDimnDsD/Dq8K8P8SH//9jb2RlZ29sZg)

Got trouble with 05AB1E `ć` (extract 1) leaving an empty string/list on the stack  after the last element is extracted. This solution would be 1-2 bytes shorter if it weren't for that.

```
ćIgµ¶?AvDyÊið?ë¼?ć  Implicit input 
ć                   Extract the 1st char from the string
 Igµ                While counter != length of the string
    ¶?              Print a newline
      Av            For each letter of the lowercased alphabet
        DyÊ         Is the examined character different from the current letter?
           ið?      If true, then print a space

              ë¼?ć  Else increment the counter, print the letter and push
                    the next character of the string on the stack
```

Comment: Actually, `ð,` means "print a space and a newline".

Comment: You're right. Fixed the code to actually print a newline.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 101 bytes

```
StringRiffle[
  Alphabet[]/.#->" "&/@
   (Except[#|##,_String]&@@@
     Split[Characters@#,#==1&@*Order]),"
",""]&
```

[`Split`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html) the input into strictly increasing letter sequences, comparing adjacent letters with [`Order`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Order.html). If `Order[x,y] == 1`, then `x` precedes `y` in the alphabet and thus can appear on the same line.

For each sequence of letters, create a pattern to match strings [`Except`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Except.html) for those letters; `#|##` is a shorthand for [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html). Replace letters of the [`Alphabet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alphabet.html) that match the pattern with spaces.

---

Illustration of the intermediate steps:

```
"codegolf";
Split[Characters@#,#==1&@*Order]  &@%
Except[#|##,_String]&@@@         #&@%
Alphabet[]/.#->" "&/@               %
```

```
{{"c", "o"}, {"d", "e", "g", "o"}, {"l"}, {"f"}}

{Except["c" | "c" | "o", _String], 
 Except["d" | "d" | "e" | "g" | "o", _String], 
 Except["l" | "l", _String],
 Except["f" | "f", _String]}

{{" "," ","c"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","o"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "},
 {" "," "," ","d","e"," ","g"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","o"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "},
 {" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","l"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "},
 {" "," "," "," "," ","f"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "}}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 65 bytes

***-4 bytes** thanks to @pxeger, **-2 bytes** thanks to @roblogic*

```sh
repeat $#1;echo&&for y ({A-Z})printf ${(Ml:1:)1[1]%$y}&&1=${1#$y}
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanxPy2/SEFDw1rZ0FpTs7rYlgvEr1TQqHbU04uq1SzWtlWpVqnW8NU0jDaMVVWprLXSjVGoVVMzBIobKgP5XDY2NirFtf81udIUIl19fPzD/wMA)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldDNSgMxFAXgfZ7iQsZpsphCcJfWRcHZtYi6EP8WaSZpAjUpya0yDn32cYIirkSzOrkQznfznt1oGWejjQkYW1Cx4NxoF@u6THpgw2o@fzjxQ/IBLVQD2@ylkFw8iuezqj/VtbioBkGnOHJi4b5dr6/uSDmUUrhpV5ebFiglcrmcXc8IuVWvBgRse8hvHrXzYQc2xRfImErWMWiFJij0MQBG@GyWhPyZWJDfQNk8wU/ll@C8CPbGYnNQXVeKjdJumiCaVGrVlMMOHUQ7cX3IaFRXLvm4zejxiOWRR5i2cCCbf/h@@cIP)</s>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldBPS8MwGAbwez7FC6lde@ggeOvmYWBvG6IexD87pGmyBGpSkndKLfvsNUGR4UEwp@cNhOf35iPoOUh0A0LruZBC9EQVZTF7OUiOkFG2kkK7PFfOwwjFtKmeTuXgjUUF2VTs@prVJXtm@4tsPOU5u8omRmOcS6Lgsdlubx5IOpRSuGs217sGKCX1er24XRByz98kMGhHCO8GhTb2AMq7VwjoUxbOCo7ScjTOAjr4aq4JSZ6iWEVfWf4SLpfnxIT8AdbVC5wrvwWXSdBLhdXAuy4VSy50vEGUPtXymO0BNTgVucYGlLxLQzi2AQ0eMT0yCHELDXX1D98fX/gJ)

Append to `$s` a `(M)` matched letter, `(l:1:)` left-padded to one character, then remove the letter if it matches the start of `$1`.

Comment: -4 on the second solution: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldDNSgMxFAXgfZ7iQsZpsphCcJfWRcHZtYi6EP8WaSZpAjUpya0yDn32cYIirkSzOrkQznfznt1oGWejjQkYW1Cx4NxoF@u6THpgw2o@fzjxQ/IBLVQD2@ylkFw8iuezqj/VtbioBkGnOHJi4b5dr6/uSDmUUrhpV5ebFiglcrmcXc8IuVWvBgRse8hvHrXzYQc2xRfImErWMWiFJij0MQBG@GyWhPyZWJDfQNk8wU/ll@C8CPbGYnNQXVeKjdJumiCaVGrVlMMOHUQ7cX3IaFRXLvm4zejxiOWRR5i2cCCbf/h@@cIP)

Comment: Rules don't permit leading spaces, but nice 3 byte save

Comment: It is allowed: "Are leading newlines allowed?" -- "Sure, as long as it doesn't mess up grid structure."

Comment: Ah, I didn't read the comments, just the main post.

Comment: Save 1 byte using `repeat $#1 ` instead of `for ((;#1;))`

Comment: Save another byte using `setopt braceccl` :) [try it online](https://tio.run/##ldBPS8MwGAbwez7FC6lde@ggeOvmYWBvG6IexD87pGmyBGpSkndKLfvsNUGR4UEwp@cNhOf35iPoOUh0A0LruZBC9EQVZTF7OUiOkFG2kkK7PFfOwwjFtKmeTuXgjUUF2VTs@prVJXtm@4tsPOU5u8omRmOcS6Lgsdlubx5IOpRSuGs217sGKCX1er24XRByz98kMGhHCO8GhTb2AMq7VwjoUxbOCo7ScjTOAjr4aq4JSZ6iWEVfWf4SLpfnxIT8AdbVC5wrvwWXSdBLhdXAuy4VSy50vEGUPtXymO0BNTgVucYGlLxLQzi2AQ0eMT0yCHELDXX1D98fX/gJ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>130</s> 126 bytes

```
$
¶A
{-2=`
$'
}T`RL`_o`.$
+`(?<=(.)*)((.).*¶(?<-1>.)*(?(1)(?!)).+\3.*$)
 $2
(?<=(.)*)((.).*¶(?<-1>.)*(?<-1>\3.*$))
¶$2
}`¶.*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fhevQNkeual0j2wQuFXWu2pCEIJ@E@PwEPRUu7QQNextbDT1NLU0NIKmndWgbUEDX0A4oomGvYaipYa@oqamnHWOsp6WiyaWgYsSFTwOIAVGqCbQTqLg24dA2IJfr/39HvxBPF89g1@AQRycfz2APX1e/EMcgT0c/z2BfAA) Edit: Saved 4 bytes by using @MartinEnder's alphabet generator. Explanation:

```
$
¶A
{-2=`
$'
}T`RL`_o`.$
```

Append the alphabet.

```
+`(?<=(.)*)((.).*¶(?<-1>.)*(?(1)(?!)).+\3.*$)
 $2
```

Align as many letters as possible with their position in the alphabet.

```
(?<=(.)*)((.).*¶(?<-1>.)*(?<-1>\3.*$))
¶$2
```

Start a new line before the first letter that could not be aligned.

```
}`¶.*$
```

Delete the alphabet, but then do everything over again until there are no misaligned letters.

Comment: This seems to print only one line, not aligning letters on subsequent lines.

Comment: @JustinMariner My bad, I made a typo in my last golf and failed to check it properly.

Answer (score 2):

## Golfscript, <s>22</s> 21 bytes

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJDT0RFR09MRiIKey5uPnt9eycKJ1x9aWY6bn0lOm47)

*-1 byte thanks to careful final redefining of the `n` built-in.*

```
{.n>{}{'
'\}if:n}%:n;
```

Explanation (with a slightly different version):

```
{.n>{}{"\n"\}if:n}%:n; # Full program
{                }%    # Go through every character in the string
 .n>         if        # If ASCII code is greater than previous...
                       # (n means newline by default, so 1st char guaranteed to fit)
    {}                 # Do nothing
      {"\n"\}          # Else, put newline before character
               :n      # Redefine n as the last used character
                   :n; # The stack contents are printed at end of execution
                       # Literally followed by the variable n, usually newline
                       # So because n is by now an ASCII code...
                       # ...redefine n as the new string, and empty the stack
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 80 bytes

```
^
;¶
{`;.*
¶;ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
¶¶
¶
)+`;(.*)(.)(.*¶)\2
$.1$* $2;$3
;.*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/jsv60Dau6gRrPS2uQ9usHZ2cXVzd3D08vbx9fP38AwKDgkNCw8IjIqOAskCFQKSpnWCtoaelqaEHRFqHtmnGGHGp6BmqaCmoGFmrGHOBTPr/39EvxNPFM9g1OMTRyccz2MPX1S/EMcjT0c8z2BcA)

There is always exactly one leading newline. The code somewhat clunkily prepends the word with the alphabet along with a marker (semicolon).  It then moves the marker up to the first letter of the word, while changing all other letters it passes into spaces. It also removes the first letter of the word. It repeats this until the first letter of the word isn't after the marker anymore. Then it clears that marker and the rest of the alphabet, and replaces it with a new line and the alphabet with a marker again. It keeps repeating this until the input word is empty, then it cleans up the last alphabet and marker, leaving the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

## [q/kdb+](http://kx.com/download/), <s>48</s> 45 bytes

**Solution:**

```
-1{@[26#" ";.Q.A?x;:;x]}@/:(0,(&)(<=':)x)_x:;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/4f6Gil5Ojk7OLq5u7h6eXt4@vnHxAYFBwSGhYeERml9D/BwKraIdrITFlJQck60NG@wtrKuiK21kHfSkOtTsNO3UqzQjO@wkrJydHHx9/fT8n6/38A)

**Note:** Link is to a [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok) port of this solution as there is no TIO for q/kdb+.

**Examples:**

```
q)-1{@[26#" ";.Q.A?x;:;x]}@/:(0,(&)(<=':)x)_x:"STACKEXCHANGE";
                  ST
A C       K
    E                  X
  C    H
A            N
      G
    E

q)-1{@[26#" ";.Q.A?x;:;x]}@/:(0,(&)(<=':)x)_x:"BALLOON";
 B
A          L
           L  O
              O
             N
```

**Explanation:**

Q is interpreted right-to-left. The solution is split into two parts. First split the string where the next character is less than or equal to the current:

`"STACKEXCHANGE"` -> `"ST","ACK","EX","CH","AN","G","E"`

Then take a string of 26 blanks, and apply the input to it at the indices where the input appears in the alphabet, and print to stdout.

`"__________________________"` -> `__________________ST______`

Breakdown:

```
-1{@[26#" ";.Q.A?x;:;x]}each(0,where (<=':)x) cut x:; / ungolfed solution
-1                                                  ; / print to stdout, swallow return value
                                                  x:  / store input as variable x
                                              cut     / cut slices x at these indices
                            (               )         / do this together
                                     (<=':)x          / is current char less-or-equal (<=) than each previous (':)?
                               where                  / indices where this is true
                             0,                       / prepended with 0
                        each                          / take each item and apply function to it
  {                    }                              / lambda function with x as implicit input
   @[      ;      ; ; ]                               / apply[variable;indices;function;arguments]
     26#" "                                           / 26 take " " is "      "...
            .Q.A?x                                    / lookup x in the uppercase alphabet, returns indice(s)
                   :                                  / assignment
                     x                                / the input to apply to these indices
```

**Notes:**

- -3 bytes by replacing prev with the K4 version

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>129</s> 117 bytes

```r
function(s){z={}
y=diff(x<-utf8ToInt(s)-64)
z[diffinv(y+26*(y<0))+x[1]]=LETTERS[x]
z[is.na(z)]=" "
write(z,1,26,,"")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5Ba8IwAIXv/RUlXpKZDpVRPDSHOOMWiC2YnNb1UGoDAUmlja6t@Nu7CJ68Pd734HvtpMMkmvTFVs40FnboNpLbPRjI0WgN@yS6OL1WDbfOsyj@QMGYP5CxVzjMV/EbHJIFQvM@XxYFEUwpdpB5X/iZ6d5tCUdUEBCC4K81roYjXuJVjDEA6D5pCD6zLfvKxA6goCodBL/WJ9/TVPEtl0wquhFcfu9ZquiB05TL/et2Q4XIsvSlPped97X1FT5PIVw1p1N57mri7SicheAnomD6Bw)

Explanation (ungolfed):

```r
function(s){
 z <- c()                  # initialize an empty vector
 x <- utf8ToInt(s)-64      # map to char code, map to range 1:26
 y <- diff(x)              # successive differences of x
 idx <- cumsum(c(          # indices into z: cumulative sum of:
    x[1],                  # first element of x
    ifelse(y<=0,y+26,y)))  # vectorized if: maps non-positive values to themselves + 26, positives to themselves
 z[idx] <- LETTERS[x]      # put letters at indices
 z[is.na(z)] <- " "        # replace NA with space
 write(z,"",26,,"")        # write z as a matrix to STDOUT ("") with 26 columns and empty separator.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>87</s> 85 bytes

```python
def f(s,l=65):c,*t=s;o=ord(c)-l;return o<0and'\n'+f(s)or' '*o+c+(t and f(t,o-~l)or'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNo1gnx9bMVNMqWUerxLbYOt82vyhFI1lTN8e6KLWktChPId/GIDEvRT0mT10bqFozv0hdQV0rXztZW6NEASgBNKJEJ1@3Lgcko675v6AoM69EI01D3dHJWV1T0xrC1@SCizs7OWIVd3L08fH390OS@w8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 39 bytes

```
(_65+3 u:[)}&(26{.'')/.~0+/\@,2>:/\3&u:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc5BC4IwAMXxu5/iHcJNJk6UPIyKvkdGzBo40W24eYr66otFt84P3v83xeiOAvTW7VmLTVyKV06b7lkRUvDqXTPen8vmJHjf5puI6j5aHByC3ZxTK8gg59laQ7K/RZqgH9orH@Qwaz8uygS5amm0X0iWoumb1ijRIAWQCgW@FjAkDX6cHUHi4Bo/)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
Ｆθ«Ｊ⌕αι⁺ⅉ‹⌕αιⅈι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBo1BToZqL06s0tyAkX8MtMy9FI1FHIVNTRyEgp7RYI1IDyPJJLS5GkYrQ0AQCay7OgKLMvBKNTCCz9v9/R78QTxfPYNfgEEcnH89gD19XvxDHIE9HP89g3/@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 θ              Input string
Ｆ «             Loop over characters
     α     α    Uppercase letters predefined variable
      ι     ι   Current character
    ⌕     ⌕     Find index
             ⅈ  Current X co-ordinate
         ‹      Compare
        ⅉ       Current Y co-ordinate
       ⁺        Sum
   Ｊ            Jump to aboslute position
              ι Print current character
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 20 bytes

```apl
⊃¨⎕a∘.∩⍨⊢⊂⍨1,2≥/⎕a⍳⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZXLTsJAFIb3PMXZDSR4Xbob2oEOl3Jpue4aLoZIggE3xrhBYwBTowsT1yQm6Na4cemjzIvgBLBSKJyi/otmOvP1zMzp/Ges09ZO7dxqtY93qi2r221WJ@LusdkWN/f7k4Z8iuHV51h2WaL/tCv6L8Iei@FIDHuycRA@FIPnvemo/Sa7J5Mz@cmFsN/FYNSRzYawP45Iw2q2SLAm7Ff5Kgc7IXF7Tdon5DIQqMN0kh4BUOBH6YU2CdTDDgQqgxgKfSsJLi1DUfAQCRAlrbJYOhklcjsPddcil2WYK6Gps5MEbJyfrYYrLUHTSJrXIhemW5C@abtO4rZb0ywnhkmVBCspGtVjzEdi5qp4/xiXyoBDJcChIuBQAXAoDzhkAg4ZgEM5wKEs4FAGcAj3C3aAZkoB/NV5fuwxVRxwiAMOaYBDPuyxrmT48pCrjAEOKYBDEcAhCushUimXioW8aeSymbSeSibiXItFmapEqGNyGSaMJSAYJlESWi4LHrXJ/PVvVN2Q4Sf5XuU5ssUh5T7MrKGeYFgK6DZlgf/TbeBvd56OJ1Q3ucoNJm@FSJIbWorpJs1xqnMjNT83Xw)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
{{x@x?`c$65+!26}'(&~>':x)_x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZRPa8JAEMXvforXIFUpvRTqIYG2m2RNVk2iJmpUpJaCpVgsiIeI6FdP/W/UZGLbdwr82N2ZyXszuh9/jMNwKM/nwUvwPHjPFh/vbh6Ki1z@dvmUk4PCa7AIp/I825stJ/IQQKAMvkdKfjB8@/xSAmWmTAr9RWbakzRH54ZTLUkZIC8BGo5yIt9rjhWHzmFQfK8qThThJcRIKvTX5bge0yrc10xmG3xf07lcL3onO9RcQdKb/PIS/8g3582Ymnb3R2Qn9HSYydXvH3vudvx2q@m5jXrNsa1qpSxMo8R1TWVJA9ipezH0E3VAch8kb4PkLZC8CZJ7ILkLkjdA8jpIXgPJSVMTBtjKAv4WihQDb1QGyQVIboLktIETQptm8MPSAMk1kFwFyVliQHYBY7YndOHy1XJRq8I1LW57rCGYLVxrG7GYjHu/HLF@yt2UEZ3tMPU6iwg6IiZlQU70x66MmPjXjkytPy5Cq18Y/gA)

`{` `}` function with argument `x`

`>':x` for each char, is it greater than the previous char?

`~` negate

`&` where (at which indices) do we have true

`(` `)_x` cut `x` at those indices, return a list of strings

`{` `}'` for each of those strings

```
`c$65+!26
```

the English alphabet

`x?` find the index of the first occurrence of each letter in `x`, use `0N` (a special "null" value) if not found

`x@` index `x` with that; indexing with `0N` returns `" "`, so we get a length-26 string in which the letters from `x` are at their alphabetical positions and everything else is spaces

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, <s>70</s> 63 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks @Veskah*

```powershell
$args|%{if($_-le$p){$x;rv x}
$x=("$x"|% *ht($_-65))+($p=$_)}
$x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lsSi9uEa1OjNNQyVeNydVpUCzWqXCuqhMoaKWS6XCVkNJpUKpRlVBK6MEpMDMVFNTW0OlwFYlXhMk/x9I5CrYKig5@7u4uvv7uClxqamkKTjk/v8PAA)

Explanation:

For each character in the splatted argument:

- Output string `$x` and clear `$x` value (`rv` is alias for [Remove-Variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Remove-Variable)), if a code of the current character less or equivalent (`-le`) to a code of the previous character.
- Append spaces and the current character to `$x`, store it to `$x`. Also it freshes a previous character value.

Output last `$x`.

Comment: [63 Bytes using splatting](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZbzfVfJbEovbhGtTozTUMlXjcnVaVAs1qlwrqoTKGilkulwlZDSaVCqUZVQSujBKTAzFRTU1tDpcBWJV4TJP@fq5aLSyVXwVZBycPVx8ff1z/EX4lLTSVNwcH3PwA "PowerShell – Try It Online"). Tried to use `|% *ht` to save some bytes but looks like it broke even.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 95 bytes

Just run through the upper case alphabet repeatedly while advancing a counter by 1 if you encounter the letter in the counter position of the word and printing out the letter, a space otherwise.

```r
function(s)while(F>""){for(l in LETTERS)cat("if"((F=substr(s,T,T))==l,{T=T+1;l}," "));cat("
")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcrLCoJAFIDhvU8hZzWHbNHaDCYddcpLOafrrqQhQRS80EJ8dotq@fN/zaSX80n3Vd4VdcVafD2L8sH8FQAOum5YaRaVGQkikSnMbx2DQgNjvtP297ZrWGuRRYiOU1oDOTRb2OVogQmI9lcbgOOkGbipJ4I08gGNT10v59PxQCrb79IkjrYbGQa@8Nw1//0/4wlJTyqhiK8jqcJYJMQzyROpYsDpDQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 37 bytes

```
64:a;{.a>{}{'
'\64:a;}if.a-(' '*\:a}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/38zEKtG6Wi/Rrrq2Wp1LPQbMr81M00vU1VBXUNeKsUqsVf3/39HJ2cXVzd3D08vbx9fPPyAwKDgkNCw8IjIqKjIiPCw0JDgoMMDfz9fH28vTw93N1cXZyREA)

I did a Golfscript one under a different name, but it had incorrect output.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, 62 bytes

Scans the input string for sequences of increasing letters, and for each sequence, replace letters not in the sequence with spaces.

```ruby
g=*?A..?Z
$_.scan(/#{g*??}?/){puts g.join.tr"^#$&"," "if$&[0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcvbCoIwAIDh@z1FLImSWr1AjKlLl3Mrt85UVJDYhYaHixBfvRVB//X3F/X1ZUwytTFBCO@BdUbl7ZL1x90msTFu8XjQPOuq7CTokacZqgp46lo9OIQdmN6t3mFybM0PwNE/aFzpUV/yGVCauCHdugERPgX73XazXmkVLxdSRDycs8CfUc91CCBCM48p@h0czlQQUaFJzIhgKgIO4VxK8c6fVZpnpRllHw)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
Çü@0šÅ¡vð₂×yAykǝ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9vc2FiaWX//8OHw7xAMMWhw4XCoXbDsOKCgsOXeUF5a8edLP//Y29kZWdvbGZhbmRwcm9ncmFtbWluZ3B1enpsZXM)

```
Ç       push a list of ascii values of the input        [84, 69, 83, 84]
ü@      determine which letter is >= the next letter    [1, 0, 0]
0š      prepend a 0 (false) to that list                [0, 1, 0, 0]
Å¡      split input on true values                      [["T"], ["E", "S", "T"]]
v       for each list entry
  ð₂×     push 26 spaces
  y       push list entry (letters)
  Ayk     push the positions of that letters in the alphabet
  ǝ       replace characters c in string a with letters b
  ,       print the resulting string
        implicitly close for-loop
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 91 bytes

```
A"$>}\$<>~,<.'~<\.';<.>$${}\../<..>=<...-/.$/=*=32;.>~<>"){-\}.>_{A}\\../010<$..>;=~<$@{{Z'
```

More readably:

```
      A " $ > } \
     $ < > ~ , < .
    ' ~ < \ . ' ; <
   . > $ $ { } \ . .
  / < . . > = < . . .
 - / . $ / = * = 3 2 ;
  . > ~ < > " ) { - \
   } . > _ { A } \ \
    . . / 0 1 0 < $
     . . > ; = ~ <
      $ @ { { Z '
```

And with color paths:
[image]

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fco9C8IwEAbg/1IOgmLfVB1zORr8WoTuciAOpU66Wo7kr8d2eabnPf5e0/cz15oakqzEUnYMV1jhAkOILCvgGZC4gNaDfNzG4yFACkuzsVYz5Gkp6zq7fce07BALU2/2cLWehvPlNtyvfw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>24</s> 21 bytes

3 bytes thanks to Erik the Outgolfer.

```
O64;I%26’⁶ẋÐ€;"⁸Ẏs26Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUgAt/9qZWxsef//TzY0O0klMjbigJnigbbhuovDkOKCrDsi4oG44bqOczI2Wf///0FOVElESVNFU1RBQkxJU0hNRU5UQVJJQU5JU00)

Comment: I believe this fails for input "BALLOON" - the repeated characters are on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
±E⁄Z*{@;eJι=?Xē}}¹∑z⁄n
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JUIxRSV1MjA0NFoqJTdCQCUzQmVKJXUwM0I5JTNEJTNGWCV1MDExMyU3RCU3RCVCOSV1MjIxMXoldTIwNDRu,inputs=Q09ERUdPTEY_)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>22</s> <s>21</s> <s>19</s> 17 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Zgarb (and a new language feature)

```
mȯΣẊṠ:ȯR' ←≠:'@ġ>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9odXNr//9tyK/Oo@G6iuG5oDrIr1InIOKGkOKJoDonQMShPv///0FOVElESVNFU1RBQkxJU0hNRU5UQVJJQU5JU00)

#### Explanation

```
               ġ>    Group into increasing sublists
mȯ                   To each sublist apply the following three functions
            :'@      ¹Append '@' (The character before 'A') to the start
   Ẋ                 ²Apply the following function to all adjacent pairs
           ≠            Take the difference of their codepoints
          ←             Minus 1
      ȯR'               Repeat ' ' that many times
    Ṡ:                  Append the second argument to the end.
  Σ                  ³concatenate
```

Comment: [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9odXNr//9tyK/Oo@G6iuG5oDrDtm1LJyB0dOKApjonQMShPv///0FOVElESVNFU1RBQkxJU0hNRU5UQVJJQU5JU00) with the new binary overloading of `Ṡ`.

Comment: @Zgarb Wow fancy!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 87 bytes

```js
f=([...s])=>s[0]?(g=i=>i>35?`
`+f(s):(i-parseInt(s[0],36)?" ":s.shift())+g(i+1))(10):""
```

Accepts uppercase or lowercase input. Output match the case of the input.

### Tests

```js
f=([...s])=>s[0]?(g=i=>i>35?`
`+f(s):(i-parseInt(s[0],36)?" ":s.shift())+g(i+1))(10):""

;O.innerText=["CODEGOLF","STACKEXCHANGE","F","ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA","ANTIDISESTABLISHMENTARIANISM"]
.map(f).join("=".repeat(26)+"\n")
```

```html
<pre id=O>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>81 74</s> 73 bytes

```
q@(w:y)!(x:z)|w==x=x:y!z|1<2=min ' 'x:q!z
x!_=x
a=['A'..'Z']++'\n':a
(!a)
```

Saved 1 byte thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni)!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY1Na8IwAEDv@RVJENIiLWzHsMBim7bRNtWmm99IwMmG2s1NMRb/e@dVvPT83uN9mr/tx27XNIdX50wvLnIsrd3rmTHLLL2g@vr08sz2XxUkkFh6QDWwaMUsMGxOOPF9MiPLbpcsKkIN2DAHGbfZm5vP4PobQPhzOurjb1rBDtxAHOShiPM0wvcEe56HH2Rd8mAgJkHCVSxaFbPpZPz@VupiNMxVlg76MokjEQY93irnqpSh1OI27qVSJ5lQJS8kV1JnGDT/)

#### Haskell Hugs optimizations

1. [The Hugs interpreter](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/) allows me to save one more byte by doing `(!cycle$['A'..'Z']++"\n")` instead of: `(!cycle(['A'..'Z']++"\n"))`, but [GHC does not like the former](https://tio.run/##jY3bCoIwAEDf/YptBFPCoB6lQUuXrnRWs3sR0YUis5vRlP7deo1eej7ncPar@3Ebx0VxbehPKzOgrqzceD0JUURZGcxf1XqNnA4JwAAr6wpzTcElUdqO6HCdreNtaYYprlTwFC/KZTRPkFGcVh@fgM1ZA@DySGV68xNQAjuA7NBhbui30DdBpmmiH1lG1O6wse1R4bK/iulkPBoOItnvdUMR@J0299wWc@wm/SunIuIOl@wzbvpcegETEe1zKrgMkFa8AQ). *(This is now obsolete; Laikoni already rewrote that line in a way that saved 1 byte.)*
2. Apparently, Hugs also does not require parentheses around the list pattern matcher, so I could save two more bytes going from: `q@(w:y)!(x:z)` to `q@(w:y)!x:z`.

Comment: You can save a byte with `a=['A'..'Z']++'\n':a;(!a)`. Interesting to now that Hugs seems to have somewhat laxer rules.

Comment: @Laikoni I'm looking at Haskell for months now and it doesn't cease to amaze me. I love the `a=...:a` trick. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if you are aware of this but I think its worth mentioning.  The reason Hugs is different here is that there is lower operator precedence for user defined operators than in the ghc.

Comment: @WheatWizard I wasn't aware. This makes perfect sense, given the error I got in GHC.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 63 bytes

```
d5*v
(?;\i:0
~{?\}::{::}@=::{$" ["a${=:}?$~@?$~o10d2*-{?$~{+}}?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P8VUq4xLw946JtPKgKuu2j6m1sqq2sqq1sEWSKsoKUQrJapU21rV2qvUOQBxvqFBipGWbjWQWa1dW2v//7@To4@Pv78fAA)

Input is expected in uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>133</s> <s>131</s> 129 bytes

```
fun r(s:String){var c=0
while(0<1){('A'..'Z').map{if(c==s.length)return
if(s[c]==it){print(s[c])
c++}else print(" ")}
println()}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY49C4MwFEX3/IrgYh5CsGsxhdKvpeDQraVDCFFDYyrP2FJCfrsNeqd7z3A5r7e3xs1zMzmKbNzSm0fjWggfiVSJknw7YzUrqw0EwvJ9znl@z4H3cgimYUqIkVvtWt8Baj@hI4mOD/UUwngIQzrzywaiiiJqO2q6woxmEMnSrWMQ4@LQS@OYxDaZ7BHlr1p9dkADoSnIskN9PF3q6zkDEuc/)

### Explained

```
fun r(s: String) {
    // Current character
    var c = 0
    // Keep going until the end of the string
    while (0 < 1) {
        // Go through the letters
        ('A'..'Z').map{
            // If the word is done then stop
            // Have to check after each letter
            if (c == s.length) return
            // If we are at the right letter
            if (s[c] == it) {
                // Print it
                print(s[c])
                // Go to the next letter
                c++
            // Otherwise print space
            } else print(" ")
        }
        // Put a newline between the lines
        println()
    }
}
```

### Test

```
fun main(args:Array<String>)=r("CODEGOLF")
```

**Edit: Ran through my compressor, saved 2 bytes.**

Answer (score 1):

### C++, <s>202</s> 197 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using c=std::string;void f(c s){std::cout<<c(s[0]-65,32)<<s[0];for(int i=1;i<s.size();++i)std::cout<<(s[i]>s[i-1]?c(s[i]-s[i-1]-1,32):"\n"+c(s[i]-65,32))<<s[i];}
```

Comment: I think `(s[i]>s[i-1])`=>`s[i]>s[i-1]` works, along with moving the `int i=1` to the for-loop.

Comment: Also, `("\n"+c(s[i]-65,32))` => `"\n"+c(s[i]-65,32)`

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 121 bytes

```
<?$p=$argv[1];$b=substr;while($p){for($i=A;$i!=AA;$i++){if($p[0]==$i){echo$b($p,0,1);$p=$b($p,1);}else echo" ";}echo'
';}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxl6lwFYlsSi9LNow1lolyba4NKm4pMi6PCMzJ1VDpUCzOi2/SEMl09bRWiVT0dYRRGlra1ZnpgElow1ibW1VMjWrU5Mz8lWSgCI6BjqGmtYgI8E8ILs2Nac4VQGkQElBCcgDMtS51K1r////7@jk7OLp5ecfFBwSGuXo5OoG4YSFR0FkvH184ZIQKRgdFeXs7@Lq7u/j9i@/oCQzP6/4v24eAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin, 101 bytes

*Port of the [Powershell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173735/80745).*

```kotlin
{s:String->var p=' '
var x=""
var r=""
s.map{c->if(c<p){r+=x+"\n";x=""}
x=x.padEnd(c-'A')+c
p=c}
r+x}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 163 bytes

```rust
|s:&str|{let mut s=s.bytes().peekable();while s.peek().is_some(){for c in 65..91{print!("{}",if Some(c)==s.peek().cloned(){s.next();c}else{32}as char)}println!()}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBSgMxFEX38xWvs5AEJKCioMMsprRgwM7CzF6m8YUGM5mSl6KS5tvHtAvv8p57bjhRXIyHabSecUiVwwgG2uVMLzcUwzldiukUgVoS@9@IxLg4In6Ne4eMN98H6xDoWhVi6YPmqYBk5gAarIenRyGe79IxWB9XrE65vrUG1GWledv@q9rNHj@LScLjTyzfOqMjTA/3eSTQhzHwfH1xfsV4zktTQYlhddcPciPVVg3d@k2q1922H7p32fVS7WreVHn5Aw)

### Explanation

```rust
|s:&str|{                                        // Take a single parameter s (a string)
  let mut s=s.bytes().peekable();                // Turn s into a peekable iterator
  while s.peek().is_some(){                      // While s is nonempty:
    for c in 65..91{                             //   For every c in range [65, 91) (uppercase alphabet):
      print!("{}",if Some(c)==s.peek().cloned(){ //     If the next character in s is the same as c:
        s.next();                                //       Advance the iterator
        c                                        //       Print c as a character
      } else {                                   //     Else:  
        32                                       //       Print a space
      } as char)                                 //
    }                                            //
    println!()                                   //   Print a newline
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü→Δe-Y─▲99╣w
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=811aff652d59c41e3939b977&i=CODEGOLF%0ASTACKEXCHANGE%0AZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA%0AF%0AANTIDISESTABLISHMENTARIANISM%0ABALLOON&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
{<!}    block tests if one value is >= another
)       use block to split input into partitions by testing adjacent pairs
m       map partitions using rest of the program and output
  zs    put a zero-length array under the partition in the stack
  F     for each letter in the array, run the rest of the program
    65- subtract 65 (ascii code for 'A')
    _&  set the specified index to the character, extending the array if necessary
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7B%3C%21%7D+++%09block+tests+if+one+value+is+%3E%3D+another%0A%29++++++%09use+block+to+split+input+into+partitions+by+testing+adjacent+pairs%0Am++++++%09map+partitions+using+rest+of+the+program+and+output%0A++zs+++%09put+a+zero-length+array+under+the+partition+in+the+stack%0A++F++++%09for+each+letter+in+the+array,+run+the+rest+of+the+program%0A++++65-%09subtract+65+%28ascii+code+for+%27A%27%29%0A++++_%26+%09set+the+specified+index+to+the+character,+extending+the+array+if+necessary&i=CODEGOLF%0ASTACKEXCHANGE%0AZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA%0AF%0AANTIDISESTABLISHMENTARIANISM%0ABALLOON&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;ó< £BôkX ¸
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=O/M8IKNC9GtYILg&input=IkNPREVHT0xGIg) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=O/M8IKNC9GtYILg&footer=V2dWClbnLSD6LTI2ClJpVXVXVlcgcFcgtw&input=WwoiQ09ERUdPTEYiCiJTVEFDS0VYQ0hBTkdFIgoiWllYV1ZVVFNSUVBPTk1MS0pJSEdGRURDQkEiCiJBTlRJRElTRVNUQUJMSVNITUVOVEFSSUFOSVNNIgpdLW0)

```
;ó< £BôkX ¸     :Implicit input of string
 ó<             :Partition between characters where the first is < the second
    £           :Map each X
;    B          :  Uppercase alphabet
      ô         :  Split at characters that return falsey (empty string)
       kX       :    When the characters in X are removed
          ¸     :  Join with spaces
                :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 114 bytes

```julia
~w=(s=[w...];r="";i=j=0;while j<length(w) s[j+1]==['A':'Z';][i+=1] ? r*=s[j+=1] : r*=" ";i>25&&(i=0;r*="\n")end;r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZVNb9pAEIbP5Ve8WlXBbhAqlXqBbqr1F3YwdoKdhM@DU9zGyHURpiIn/jq1MSBQGJd2Doj1M57Z2XlnPfsdR0HjdbNZr7iU8tGqXq9PWgvOWCviM/6xtXqJ4hCzL3GY/Fi@SCsZ6Wh23ZhwPqqKarM6rLYmo@iaNyb4isUHntN80cwXDFmYm0@fr66kKIuVPxknTA6TaWshb@aLKFnGicT01@DnPA6b42ScvJfWTHU1ve3aBpNz70plyrXo21KqvGP9wVAoKgO/AcN5y1zGSe5Uy/yNI1dj@@QQewfUo1fdo//jJPvRdLQptjf7NP2OFcmybWi60S5y7Rc58HyhdvS@agqnrVPleP4@pDhss4Nz6fQzx1Cw7XvmW5zHPDLnTAmH0s/k2xYxHPSfHh98r3d/5zpdu3NrmW1D11RFlDYIGJ4c4IkNQLI@SPYEkj2CZA8gmQ@SeSBZDyS7B8nuQDJSdETHCusC/ybWEmVt7RYks0AyEySjlQUDtOpAMg0kU0EyBSQTxfw6vqVZnp6Nq2JbntnVHV/0LOFYXnc31G974l94Rtop80pqPboJlL/30qK1alL60IkaxAUat/7rdindZ6HjbQ8UYduu6@yulLKWXSTznJWMVenIZfupZJ@jw3dLxDGWYbpMMQ/SNJw2wWoI4lgarQNwjmd8/7WAFNSeZUQJphNZ3vwB)

This solution builds the string character by character. Below is an ungolfed version:

```julia
function ~(w)
	r=""
	i=1
	j=1
	s=[w...]
	a=['A':'Z';]
	while j<=length(w)
		if s[j] == a[i]
			r*=s[j]
			j=j+1
		else
			r*=" "
		end
		i=i+1
		if i==27
			i=1
			r*="\n"
		end
	end
	r
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZVfb5swEMCf4VOc0KTAFkXqXiZl8yQDJtASaANt8/eBNmQFMTcKVOlTvnpmIIkSNcey3YMx/p19d76znb5lSXT1vt0u3vhzkbxy2KhrTZZWRFFkKSFXspSWTU4m606nM5OliExatNVtjVvfxd/6JcliSH@QLOa/ipdqrpQsIJ@kMyAEokkitCRp9ZmUQ2U3JekXsaIUZ3m8Qwoo5QCfl5NJUmGxSELI12@lSuVHrTnlB9WqWcnis12uEl5kXFXYe/R7mcXdKZ/yT@pGMXyT9XzXUjQxUZPlOTGT50KVJWU4GlPdUID8BAXOi1CZ8lKpLfStI1WrGjmsvQPG0VT/qD/lojEZ9DC2F/fU/I7VxoQbJrN6ta39TwmCkBo3bGjY1OsxLJwg3C9JD27ewDlz7Mw21KyaZ3/E5ZpH4p0J4RD6GXtVEOPR8PHhPgwGd7e@13dvrh27ZzHT0GljggDGJxt4IiNA2RBQ9ggoewCU3QPKQkBZACgbAMruAGW3gDK06JCM1dIH@LdibaisSq4BZQ6gzAaU4ZUFFuBVBygzAWUGoEwHlNH6/HqhYzoBE8dVd53A7jMvpAOHek7Q3x3qjzkJL9wj85QFDbEe3QT633Pp4LVqY/XBkBjoBTXu/Nft0uhnXcdVDnTqur7v7a6UppRdVOYlazhWjUdO@COL5@jwbtEsgyLOixyWUZ7H8y4obYiyTJ1sovIdfYLF6wrUqP2kQcJhPtO07R8)

The following alternative approach builds a string of spaces for each character and inserts newlines afterwards. Strings are immutable in Julia, but if there is a more efficient way to assemble the strings, this method might be made shorter. Additionally, I couldn't find an efficient way to interleave Strings or Characters, since this relies on using the array transpose `'`, which only works on numeric types.

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 166 bytes (alternate approach)

```julia
function f(s)
v=[s...]
r=" ".^(((q=diff(['@';v])).+25).%26).*string.(v)
map(i -> (q[i]<1 && (j='Z'-v[i-1];r[i]=r[i][1:j]*"\n"*r[i][j+1:end])),1:length(r))
join(r)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZVvc5pAEMZfl0@xw7TxzigzZKZ9YUqm/FOICImQxIh2hkRJcchphDj59hZErY4utX1eMMCPu71ln72bvMdRIH4sl@E7e06jKYOQJJRbSH4iCMKQm0s88MJPQsibNIrCkPiVH5XLxZBS4fziKxW@XHyjQjVJ5xF7EciCcq/BjERQvwLy5kfD7yKcnQGZSJV@pb7wo7o4vJxn76X84ouNybDKDxhfXT1OzsXGmI2yuWtiIx6zl/QXmVPKTaYRy264jC1nWaA0ZoTXP4LXWTxuDNiAfSYh4VVH01uO1eQpzWakHDeStOg5JdwnvsmDdAU85GrytezN9uM1UOGPnJ37Acsumg4tjG1kwZ7WrAgmK6qmN1tFrM1DDlxPVtt6TzVku6XvrHFPrreZUt4usw3HwumHg3sFW40zDnE@547sIylsUz8Sb5VE/7H3cH/nud3bG8fuWO1r02g1dU1VZCyjtfp7P3BPj4CyHqDsAVB2Dyi7A5R5gDIXUNYFlN0Cym4AZajpkIoV6gD8m1lLnLXSNaDMBJQZgDLcWdAE3HWAMg1QpgLKFECZXPSv7Zma6epZuyqW6Rod3fbkrinbpttZN/VhTbwT/5G2z9ySXHd2AuXvtTRxrxqYP3QkB/kEj5v/tbuUrrPw8aoGimxZjmOvt5Sykp1k85yVtFVpy2Xr4bLjZXsSyXEM6ThJE5gFSTIeNYCvQRDHxA9JQEGS4AnC6RxIUHuiEDHIT7jlbw)

Answer (score 0):

## Dyalog APL, <s>47</s> <s>37</s> 34 bytes

```
{↑{⍵∘{⍵∊⍺:⍵⋄' '}¨⎕A}¨⍵⊂⍨1,2≥/⎕A⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE6oftU2sftS79VHHDAjV9ah3lxWI1d2irqBee2gFUJ0jiAIKdTU96l1hqGP0qHOpPkj4Ue9moHCtuqNfiKeLZ7BrcIijk49nsIevq1@IY5Cno59nsK/6//8A)

### How? (argument is `⍵`)

- `⍵⊂⍨1,2≥/⎕A⍳⍵`, split into alphabetically ordered segments
- `{...}¨`, apply this function to each letter (argument is `⍵`):

  - `⎕A`, the alphabet
  - `...¨`, apply this function to each argument (argument is `⍵`):

    - `⍵∘`, pass `⍵` in as the left argument (`⍺`) to the function:

      - `{⍵∊⍺:⍵⋄' '}`, if `⍵` is in `⍺`, then return `⍵`, otherwise a space. This function is what creates a line of text.
- `↑`, turn into an array (equivalent of adding the newlines)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, <s>73</s> <s>71</s> 72 bytes

```
Print@@(Alphabet[]/.Except[#|##,_String]->" ")&@@@Split[#,Order@##>0&];&
(* or *)
Print@@@Outer[If[!FreeQ@##,#2," "]&,Split[#,Order@##>0&],Alphabet[],1];&
```

*sacrificed a byte to fix the output*

Takes a list of lower case characters (which is a "string" [per meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2216/60043)).

[Try it on Wolfram Sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com)

#### Usage

```
f = (Print@@(Alphabet[]/.Except[#|##,_String]->" ")&@@@Split[#,Order@##>0&];&)
```

```
f[{"c", "o", "d", "e", "g", "o", "l", "f"}]
```

> ```
>  c           o           
>   de g       o           
>           l              
>     f
> ```

Comment: Your input is a list of strings? Is this valid?

Comment: Also this outputs `{Null, Null, Null, Null}` at the end. Is this allowed by OP?

Comment: @BillSteihn Yes, per [meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2216/60043). For your second question, it prints the string to STDOUT. The `Null`s are what the expression evaluates to, not a part of STDOUT (you can see this easily on Mathematica Kernel). For now, I fixed the issue by adding a byte.

Comment: @BillSteihn the question specifies that a list of strings (i presume the list containing each line) is not a valid **output** format. I reckon it's fine as the **input** format, especially if it's a list of characters (plus, some languages have no distinction between a string and a list of characters, so disallowing this only makes the question unfair).

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 36 bytes

```
Wa{YsX26b:0Fiz{iQ@a?y@b::POau++b}Py}
```

Uses lowercase input

How?

```
Wa{YsX26b:0Fiz{iQ@a?y@b::POau++b}Py}  : One arg, string
 a                a        a          : First input, string 
Wa{                                }  : While a isn't empty
    s                                   : Space character 
     X26                                : Repeat 26 times
   Y                                    : Yank value
        b:0                             : Set b to zero
           Fiz{                 }       : For each character in z(lowercase alphabet)
                   ?                      : If
               i                          : Letter
                Q                         : Is equal to 
                 @a                       : The first letter in the input string
                       ::                 : Swap the values of
                    y@b                   : Char at index b of y
                         POa              : Head a; pop the first value of a
                            u             : Nil(Terminate else)
                             ++b          : Iterate b
                                 P      : Print; output with newline
                                  y     : Line
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJXYXtZc1gyNmI6MEZpentpUUBhP3lAYjo6UE9hdSsrYn1QeX0iLCIiLCIiLCJhbnRpZGlzZXN0YWJsaXNobWVudGFyaWFuaXNtIl0=)

Answer (score 0):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 63 bytes

```
0i:0(?;$:r:@\
'A'-=?\' 'o$\
oi$c3.\
:?!v  >$:20.\1+d2*%
   \ao/
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiMGk6MCg/OyQ6cjpAXFxcbidBJy09P1xcJyAnbyRcXFxub2kkYzMuXFxcbjo/IXYgID4kOjIwLlxcMStkMiolXG4gICBcXGFvLyIsImlucHV0IjoiQUJTVEFDS0VYQ0hBTkdFIiwic3RhY2siOiIiLCJzdGFja19mb3JtYXQiOiJudW1iZXJzIiwiaW5wdXRfZm9ybWF0IjoiY2hhcnMifQ==)

Ties the other ><> answer but a very different approach

Answer (score -1):

## Mathematica, 184 bytes

```
(t=Characters@#;s=Flatten@Table[Alphabet[],(l=Length)@t];q=1;For[i=1,i<=l@s,i++,If[s[[i]]!=t[[q]],s[[i]]=" ",q++];If[q>l@t,q--;t[[q]]=0]];StringRiffle[StringPartition[""<>s,26],"\n"])&
```